# opinion on interfacing vb.net application to excel spreadsheet

Tags: vb.net

So my question is a bit subjective to opinion, but I am a bit curious about using VBA vs the Microsoft Interop Excel Reference.  I learned VBA before anything else, and I have since moved on to .net in order to design more powerful forms.  How does the interop.excel reference work in regards to formatting a worksheet? Is it basically the same as using VBA in functionality? Such as formatting, say, column widths and rearranging data?  As well, if you know VBA (which I do) is it better to design a .net app that runs the macros in the spreadsheet or just start re-learning how to do them at runtime in vb.net?  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing Excel formatting code in .net is (opinion) better than driving your macros. First you don't have to have the macros in Excel, second you have one place to modify your code.  If you're a VBA person, you know that recording macros makes a mess of code, and then you have to strip it clean.

A couple things we've learned in my office with the Interop.  Late Binding is safer than referenced objects as it can support different installed versions of office, as long as you don't include any functionality in your code that the least supported version of office can't handle.  Also, always fully qualify your objects.  By that I mean use

```
Dim XLApp as object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLApp.Range("A1").font.bold=True
XLApp.Range("A1").font.size=12
```

Do not use

```
Dim XLApp as object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With XLApp.Range("A1")
    .font.bold=True
    .font.size=12
End With
```

There's a known issue with Office interop that the "with' clause can cause a reference to be created that no matter how well you clean up when your done, can be left hanging even after your application closes.  You can test this for yourself by creating a test app, modify some settings in a worksheet, save it and close out.  Under the write circumstances, open Task Manager, and Excel is still in your process list.

Hope this helps